# Стресс-тест от студии, или коллапс меню

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains, source-tree

Меню слева

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коллапсит после каждого билда. Я не знаю, какой доктор зло из `jetbrains`ввел подобный стресс-тест, но я бы был очень благодарен, сообщи мне кто-либо - где найти магический щит, дабы успешно победить в этой схватке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А «Project» вместо «Project files» не подойдет? «Project» не сворачивается.

Comment: А «Android» вместо «Project files» не подойдет?

Comment: @post_zeew как до него добраться, не подскажешь?В моем представлении, мы уже в project.

Comment: @NikotinN в android нет всех папок в проекте, по крайней мере раньше не было(drawable, assets), как научился в project files так там и работал всегда.

Comment: ну сейчас все эти папки есть. а по поводу Project - там же где выбираешь Android/Project Files/*** там же есть Project.